# How to convert a text to dateTime

Tags: apex, visualforce, datetime

How can i convert a string like this `Wed Aug 07 04:30:00 GMT 2013` to a dateTime value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Map <String, Integer> monthNames = new Map <String, Integer> {'Jan'=>1, 'Feb'=>2, 'Mar'=>3, 'Apr'=>4, 'May'=>5, 'Jun'=>6, 'Jul'=>7, 'Aug'=>8, 'Sep'=>9, 'Oct'=>10, 'Nov'=>11, 'Dec'=>12};
List <String> stringParts = 'Wed Aug 07 04:30:00 GMT 2013'.split(' ');
List <String> timeParts = stringParts[3].split(':');

DateTime yourDateVariable = DateTime.newInstanceGmt(Integer.valueOf(stringParts[5]), monthNames.get(stringParts[1]), Integer.valueOf(stringParts[2]), Integer.valueOf(timeParts[0]), Integer.valueOf(timeParts[1]), Integer.valueOf(timeParts[2]));
```

Comment: not working any other suggestion

Comment: I just executed the above code in the developer console and this is the result - `16:53:54:420 USER_DEBUG [6]|DEBUG|----------2013-08-07 04:30:00`

Comment: sorry my mistake

Answer (score 11):

Use DateTime parse method: e.g.;

```
Datetime dt = DateTime.parse('10/14/2011 11:46 AM');
```

will return date instance of String.

or try

```
String stringDate = '2013-10-05 20:03:20';

Datetime myDate = datetime.valueOf(stringDate);
```

Comment: The first example gives: `System.TypeException: Invalid date/time: 10/14/2011 11:46 AM`

Comment: @dzh It doesn't! This was checked.

Comment: I think it parses based on user locale. I think my locale is set to use 24-hour time format.