# How do I convert text to datetime?

Tags: apex

In our legacy system feed we are getting the following text value.

```
"2016-11-17T10:04:31.000+08:00"
```

I would like to know whether it is possible to convert this text value to a datetime data type.

```
2016-11-17T18:04:31.000Z
```

Comment: Is this help http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15098/how-to-convert-a-text-to-datetime

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [JSON](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) to convert to a native datetime value:

```
DateTime t = (DateTime)json.deserialize('"2016-11-17T10:04:31.000+08:00"', datetime.class);
```

Make sure you include the surrounding quotes. Note that the time will appear, by default, in your local time zone when you debug it, but you can use formatGMT or JSON.serialize to convert it back to GMT.

Note: 10:00+08:00 is actually 02:00Z, not 18:00Z.

Comment: this is awesome.I tried it just now.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox. Thats an awesome answer. But can you shed some light on how and why this worked? The input string in the deserialize is not json!! So how can we deserialize it?

Comment: @salesforceMann Salesforce's JSON parser allows us to decode primitives as if they were objects. This includes Date, DateTime, Boolean, Integer, and Decimal values. It's an incredibly versatile API, although it tends to be kind of expensive (i.e. uses lots of CPU time) for larger objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer fox....quick question can you explain how is "10:00+08:00 is actually 02:00Z, not 18:00Z"...I am not able to understand the rationale behind this

Comment: @AaronWilfred +08:00 means that 8 hours is *added* to GMT, so to find GMT, you have to *subtract* the same. The same would be true for -08:00; 8 hours is *subtracted* from GMT, so to find GMT you have to *add* the same. The notation is a bit confusing at first (even I have to think twice every time I deal with time zones), but once you work it out on paper, it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered by sfdcFox and its a great answer!, but I would have solved it like this:

```
String oldD = '2016-11-17T10:04:31.000+08:00';

Datetime newD = Datetime.newInstance(
    Integer.valueOf(oldD.subString(0,4)), 
    Integer.valueOf(oldD.subString(5,7)),
    Integer.valueOf(oldD.subString(8,10)),  
    Integer.valueOf(oldD.subString(11,13)),
    Integer.valueOf(oldD.subString(14,16)),
    Integer.valueOf(oldD.subString(17,19))
); //this will be constructed in user timezone

system.debug('newD = '+ newD);
```

I ve taken the liberty of asking which process is better and why on this question here: 
[Converting a datetime string type to datetime type in apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149279/converting-a-datetime-string-type-to-datetime-type-in-apex)

Answer (score -1):

you can simply do like this to include the double-quotes:

```
DateTime t = (DateTime)json.deserialize('"'+var+'"', datetime.class);
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! This answer is very similar to the one that was provided by sfdcfox not quite 2 years ago. Similar answers can be fine, but the community here will generally want there to be some additional or different approach, explanation, or perspective. If you can expand on this answer, I'd encourage you to do so via an [edit]