# Converting a datetime string type to datetime type in apex

Tags: apex, json, datetime

This question is based on what I encountered on another question which goes like this:
[How do I convert text to datetime?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149239/how-do-i-convert-text-to-datetime/149241)

> In our legacy system feed we are getting the following text value.
>   "2016-11-17T10:04:31.000+08:00" I would like to know whether it is
>   possible to convert this text value to a datetime data type.
>   2016-11-17T18:04:31.000Z

Normally, I would solve it like this:

```
String oldD = '2016-11-17T10:04:31.000+08:00';
Datetime newD = Datetime.newInstance(
    Integer.valueOf(oldD.subString(0,4)), 
    Integer.valueOf(oldD.subString(5,7)),
    Integer.valueOf(oldD.subString(8,10)),  
    Integer.valueOf(oldD.subString(11,13)),
    Integer.valueOf(oldD.subString(14,16)),
    Integer.valueOf(oldD.subString(17,19))
); //this will be constructed in user timezone

system.debug('newD = '+ newD);
```

However, one fine gentleman solved it with one line of code! and it was:

```
DateTime t = (DateTime)json.deserialize('"2016-11-17T10:04:31.000+08:00"', datetime.class);
```

Of course, this one line rocks!!

Q1. Can anyone explain me how and why this actually worked? The string is not even a JSON string!

Q2. Is this mentioned in the salesforce dev docs?

Q3. If no, then how can I learn such awesome "tricks"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question of whether a single value is valid JSON is probably "it depends on which standard you consider" - see [What is the minimum valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419428/what-is-the-minimum-valid-json). Apex (at least in the JSON class) considers that it is which is arguably a helpful thing. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) even includes an example of a single value.

Internally, the JSON class is probably using a set of type conversion methods to allow it to map string values to specific type fields when a `.class` argument is supplied. For your example the `DateTime` converter is getting used.