# Why Datetime and Date class don't have more parse options for various Datetime/Date string formats

Tags: apex, date, datetime

From documentation:

**[Date Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm)**:

```
parse(stringDate)
```

> Constructs a Date from a String. The format of the String depends on
>   the **local date format**.

**[Datetime Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm)**

```
parse(datetimeString)
```

> Constructs a Datetime from the given String in the **local time zone** and
>   in the format of the **user locale**.

This quite limits the ability of a developer to work with Date/Datetime strings that are in format different from the current user's locale. As a workaround a wrapper utility class should be created to provide the parse(datetimeStringAnyFormat) method that could handle other date/datetime formats.

So why Salesforce don't support parsing different date/datetime strings natively?

Comment: I posted [an Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003ZldQAE) regarding this issue a while back. It's a significant limitation.

Comment: I think this is technically off topic but I do understand your frustration. I did upvote the idea.

Comment: I understand this might be off topic; I thought someone can clarify the reason why SF didn't implement it for so long. Since parsing dates is a common task, and not having it natively supported by apex is really frustrating. I mean there must be a reason for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why, I suspect, is the cost-benefit ratio is far too low to be worth it. Over 99.999% of typical use cases are covered by DateTime.valueOf and DateTime.parse, and the few atypical cases can be solved by other means. Since you asked about Y in an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), I can't really be more specific, but I suspect that whatever it is that you're trying to do could be solved through another technique, without writing a completely new parser that supports arbitrary locales, perhaps by using a JavaScript library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) or something else. There simply isn't enough demand for being able to parse in arbitrary locales that can't be solved through another technique.

Comment: Thank you, @sfdcfox! You answered the very question, hands down. I would argue the Y nature of my post though, since  I was indeed interested in WHY Salesforce did this, without any other context in mind (I mean exact X problem).

Comment: With that said, I still think at least one use case could have been covered by the valueOf or parse methods. It is dates in the "2016-11-17T10:04:31Z" format. One can use [JSON.deserialize](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149239/how-do-i-convert-text-to-datetime/149241#149241) method to get the DateTime object, which is quite misleading in terms of intent - I want to parse a datetime string, not deserialize JSON.

Comment: @Eduard I agree, it's unfortunate there are some situations that require JSON at all (which shouldn't be true), but like I said, I'm pretty sure it's a cost-benefit thing. And that doesn't mean this might not happen in the future, it's just got to reach a ratio where the cost-benefit ratio is worth it.